# I want to find x solution using Steepest Descent by Python. But when I was running it, it said invalid syntax at def. what should I fix about?

Tags: python-3.x

I was creating script of Steepest Descent method to solve 2 equations (The equation is on page 659 of Numerical Analysis book by Richard L. Burden and J. Douglas Faires). I have 2 scripts but both of them are exactly the same . The difference are just the definition for the equation which is I want to solve. The problem comes when I tried to run the script to solve problem on 1b.

[image: These are the exercises]

This is my script

```
    from numpy import *
def f1(x1,x2):
    return 3*x1**2-x2**2
def f2(x1,x2):
    return 3*x1*x2**2-x1**3
def g(x1,x2):
    return x1**6+(-6*x2**2+9)*x1**4+(9*x2**4-6*x2**2)*x1**2+x2**4
def dgx1(x1,x2):
    return 6*x1*(x1**4+(-4*x2**2+6)*x1**2+3*x2**4-2*x2**2
def dgx2(x1,x2):
    return (-12)*(x1**4)*x2+(36*x2**3-(12*x2))*x1**2+(4*x2**3)
x01=0
x02=0
TOL=0.05
n=100
k=1
while (k<=100):
    g1=g(x01,x02)
    z=[dgx1(x01,x02),dgx2(x01,x02)]
    z0=sqrt(z[0]**2+z[1]**2)
    if z0==0:
        print('gradien nol')
        print(x01,x02,g1)
        break
    z=z/z0
    a1=0
    a3=1
    g3=g(x01-a3*z[0],x02-a3*z[1])
    while g3>=g1:
        a3=a3/2
        g3=g(x01-a3*z[0],x02-a3*z[1])
        if a3<TOL/2:
            print('unsolve')
            print(x01,x02,g1)
            break
    a2=a3/2
    g2=g(x01-a2*z[0],x02-a2*z[1])
    h1=(g2-g1)/a2
    h2=(g3-g2)/(a3-a2)
    h3=(h2-h1)/a3
    a0=1/2*(a2-h1/h3)
    g0=g(x01-a0*z[0],x02-a0*z[1])
    Ag= min(g0,g3)
    a=a0
    g_1=g0
    if g_1!=Ag:
        a=a3
        g_1=g(x01-a3*z[0],x02-a3*z[1])
    x01=x01-a*z[0]
    x02=x02-a*z[1]
    if abs(g_1-g1)<TOL:
        print(x01,x02,g_1)
        break
    k=k+1
print(x01,x02)
```

When I ran it, it said that 'INVALID SYNTAX' and on the 'def' has red mark whose on the dgx2 line. what should I do?

Comment: This question is not specific to the Pi.  On the line before the error you have more "(" than ")" brackets, i.e. the nesting is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see.. Ok thanks..